# How OpenStruct stored in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, openstruct

I have some controller. In this controller I get OpenStruct object and want to save it to app session. Next code works fine:

```
session[:info] = OpenStruct.new(first_field: 1, second_field: 'two')
```

`p session[:info]` right after this line prints

```
#<OpenStruct first_field=1, second_field="two">
```

But after this I do redirect to another controller, and when I write `p session[:info]` in this controller I get

```
{"table"=>{"first_field"=>1, "second_field"=>"two"}}
```

So, why do I get this, and how can I load correct OpenStruct instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A session usually consists of a hash of values and a session id,
>   usually a 32-character string, to identify the hash. Every cookie sent
>   to the client's browser includes the session id. And the other way
>   round: the browser will send it to the server on every request from
>   the client.

You should either serialize your objects before storing them in the session.

```
session[:info] = OpenStruct.new(first_field: 1, second_field: 'two').to_yaml
```

and retrieve it using

```
YAML.load(session[:info])
```

from the rails documentation

> Do not store large objects in a session. Instead you should store them
>   in the database and save their id in the session. This will eliminate
>   synchronization headaches and it won't fill up your session storage
>   space (depending on what session storage you chose, see below). This
>   will also be a good idea, if you modify the structure of an object and
>   old versions of it are still in some user's cookies. With server-side
>   session storages you can clear out the sessions, but with client-side
>   storages, this is hard to mitigate.

or change your session store from `cookie_store` to `cache_store`

In your `environment` change

```
config.session_store :cookie_store
```

to

```
config.session_store :cache_store
```

Comment: Oh, my question is stupid but your answer is great. Serializing solves it.
It's enough, because my object is small.